# Finding image and kernel of group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

> Consider the groups $(\mathbb{R},+), (\mathbb{C},\times)$ together with the homomorphism $\theta:(\mathbb{R},+)\to(\mathbb{C},\times)$ defined by $\theta(x)=e^{2\pi ix}$. Find the image and kernel of this homomorphism.

My attempt is that by definition we have $Im\ \theta=\{\theta(x)\mid x\in\mathbb{R}\}$. But $e^{2\pi ix}=(e^{i\pi})^{2x}=(-1)^{2x}=1$. So $Im\ \theta=\{1\}$.

Also $\ker\theta=\{x|\ \theta(x)=0\}=\emptyset$ since the result is always $1$.

These don't seem right to me though. What should I have done differently?

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}
Im(\theta)&=\{e^{2\pi ix}|x\in\Bbb{R}\}\\
&=\{e^{iy}|y\in\Bbb{R}\}\\
&=\{\cos y+i\sin y|y\in\Bbb{R}\}\\
&=\{u+iv|u^2+v^2=1\text{ and }u,v\in\Bbb{R}\}\\
&=\{z||z|=1\text{ and } z\in\Bbb{C}\}\\
&=S^1 \text{ (The unit circle in $\Bbb{C}$)}\\
\end{align}$

$\begin{align}
Ker(\theta)&=\{x|e^{2\pi ix}=1\in\Bbb{C} \text{ and }x\in\Bbb{R}\}\\
&=\{x|\cos(2\pi x)+i\sin(2\pi x)=1+0i \text{ and }x\in\Bbb{R}\}\\
&=\{x|\cos(2\pi x)=1 \text{ and } \sin(2\pi x)=0 \text{ and }x\in\Bbb{R}\}\\
&=\{x|2\pi x=2\pi n \text{ and }n\in\Bbb{Z}\}\\
&=\{x|x=n \text{ and }n\in\Bbb{Z}\}\\
&=\{n|n\in\Bbb{Z}\}\\
&=\Bbb{Z}\\
\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

1. It is not true that $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$ holds in the complex numbers, so $e^{2\pi ix}$ is not always $1$.
2. The complex numbers with the product *is not* a group since $0$ has no inverse. You possibly mean instead the set $\Bbb C^\times := \Bbb C \setminus \{0\}$ with the product, which *is* a group.
3. As the identity element of $\Bbb C^\times$ is $1$, we have $\ker \theta = \{x \in \Bbb R : \theta(x)=1\}$.